# How can I make Plupload in D7 start uploading automatically?

Tags: media, files

I'm using the [Plupload integration](https://drupal.org/project/plupload) module and the problem is that once the users select the files, they think that they have already uploaded the files. No matter how obvious, bold and huge you make that "Start upload" button, most of them just ignore it. Plus it is not a good user experience.

What I need is for the "Start upload" button to disappear and the upload of the files into Plupload should begin automatically as soon as the files are selected. Would someone be kind enough to suggest how can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

As given in the readme file of this module add following autoupload property to your form element as shown below.

```
$form['my_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'plupload',
  '#title' => t('Upload files'),
  '#description' => t('This multi-upload widget uses Plupload library.'),
  '#autoupload' => TRUE,
);
```

I have tried it and in works fine.