# Add autoupload property after page load using plupload

Tags: 7, forms

In a form I have added a field for images, set the file source to "Advanced upload widget (Plupload)" ( all other checkboxes are unchecked ) and I get the interface. I want to make it autoupload images after being drag and droped or selected via the add image link. The form is loaded in a custom created page using a personal made module. I tried to set

```
$form['field_image_article1']['#autoupload']=TRUE
```

in myModule_form_alter and also called a myModule_after_build. None of the situations work and I can't figure out where or better sayd when should I set this value. Here is the code for the module :

```
function add_new_article_menu() {
  $items['addAnnouncement'] = array(
  'title' => 'Adauga anunt',
  'page callback' => 'add_new_article_simple_page',
  'access callback' => TRUE,
  );
return $items;
}

function add_new_article_simple_page() {
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
$node_form = new stdClass;
$node_form->type = 'announcement';
$node_form->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;
$form = drupal_get_form('announcement_node_form', $node_form);
return $form;
}
function add_new_article_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id=='announcement_node_form'){
    $form['#after_build'][]='add_new_article_after_build';
    return $form;
  }
}
function add_new_article_after_build($form, &$form_state) {
  $form['field_image_article1']['#autoupload']=TRUE;
  return $form;
}
```

Modules installed for plupload : FileField Sources Plupload,  File Field Sources , Plupload integration module

Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drupal's plupload module does not support `'#autoupload'`. Or at least that's what I experienced. I wrote my own behavior for this:

```
(function($) {

Drupal.plupload = Drupal.plupload || {};

/**
 * Attaches the Plupload behavior to each Plupload form element.
 */
Drupal.behaviors.mymodule_plupload = {
  attach: function (context, settings) {
    $(".plupload-element", context).once('mymodule-plupload-init', function () {
      var uploader = $(this).pluploadQueue();
      if(uploader !== undefined) {
        uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function(up, files) {
          $('.form-submit').prop( "disabled", true );
          uploader.start();
        });
        uploader.bind('UploadComplete', function() {
          if (uploader.files.length == (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
            // If nothing is being uploaded right now:
            $('.form-submit').prop( "disabled", false );
          }
        });
      }
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

I based it on codes and hints from the Internet, but I can't recall exact sources. I'll be happy to fix that and add reference links if someone recognizes parts of this.

Comment: interesting, let me try it out. But yes, Drupal's plupload does suport autoupload : http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87033/how-can-i-make-plupload-in-d7-start-uploading-automatically . Problem is the solution is working if I programatically create it, but nobody seems to have any info on editing after load ...

Comment: @Cristi it **is said to support** autoupload. I simply wasn't ever able to actually **see it to do so** and decided it will be easier to piece my own chunk of codes together.

Comment: Oooh , I see. Regarding the code, are there any changes I need to make for it to work on my page? I made a js file with that code , edited mymodule with the actual name, checked if its loaded in page, but still doesn't work...

Comment: Make sure your elements are correctly marked with plupload-element class, and if there are any errors in JS console - share. Oh, and consider adding some `console.log` to see if behavior is executed. Other than that? It should be generic enough. It does not contain anything related specifically to my site.

Comment: the only field I have for images has a div with plupload-element class , nu js console errors . What do you mean by adding console.log ?

Comment: @Cristi http://stackoverflow.com/q/4539253/2389310

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16528/discussion-between-cristi-and-molot).