# Where do I add this property to made plupload start the upload automatically

Tags: media, files

I found a great solution to upload images automatically, but I need help understanding where the code goes and how I figure out what the "my_element" value should be.

This is a follow-up question to an existing question but I do not have permission to comment on existing questions :/
[How can I make Plupload in D7 start uploading automatically?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87033/how-can-i-make-plupload-in-d7-start-uploading-automatically)

The code:
$form['my_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'plupload',
  '#title' => t('Upload files'),
  '#description' => t('This multi-upload widget uses Plupload library.'),
  '#autoupload' => TRUE,
);

Do I put this within the plupload.module or filefield_sources_plupload.module?
The machine name of my image field is field_image, so is that what I use in place of "my_element"?

Comment: You need to [write your own module](https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules) for that (don't hack the contrib modules). If you provide some more details about what you're trying to accomplish we may be able to help you further

Comment: Thanks, I have a simple node/add/article with an image field called field_image, and using the plupload widget.  Currently users have to click "start upload" after choose a file using "Add file".  I simply want to use the code provided to have the files upload automatically as soon as the user chooses a file.